# cannot display data from Firebase console on the android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a pretty basic quiz activity which displays questions and options from the stored JSON file in the firebase realtime database. But for some reason, nothing is displayed and the page is left blank.

here is my code fore the QuizActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.scienceapp;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b1, b2, b3, b4;
    TextView t1_question, timerTxt;
    int total = 1;
    int correct = 0;
    int wrong = 0;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    DatabaseReference database;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    b1 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b2 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b3 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
    b4 = findViewById(R.id.button5);

    t1_question = findViewById(R.id.questiontxt);
    updateQuestion();

 private void updateQuestion() {

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Questions").child(String.valueOf(total));
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        final Question question = snapshot.getValue(Question.class);


                    String ques = question.getQuestion();
                    String op1 = question.getOption1();
                    String op2 = question.getOption2();
                    String op3 = question.getOption3();
                    String op4 = question.getOption4();

                    t1_question.setText(ques);
                    b1.setText(op1);
                    b2.setText(op2);
                    b3.setText(op3);
                    b4.setText(op4);

                    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if ((b1.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer()))) {
                                b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                Handler handler = new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        correct++;
                                        b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DB7093"));

                                        updateQuestion();

                                    }
                                }, 1500);

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                wrong = wrong + 1;

                                b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                                if (b2.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer())) {
                                    b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                } else if (b3.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer())) {
                                    b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                } else if (b4.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer())) {
                                    b4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                }


                                Handler handler = new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DB7093"));
                                        b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DB7093"));
                                        b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DB7093"));
                                        b4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DB7093"));
                                        updateQuestion();
                                    }

                                }, 1500);

                            }
                        }

                    });

                    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if ((b2.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer()))) {
                                b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                Handler handler = new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        correct++;
                                        b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DB7093"));

                                        updateQuestion();

                                    }
                                }, 1500);

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                wrong = wrong + 1;

                                b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                                if (b1.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer())) {
                                    b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                } else if (b3.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer())) {
                                    b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                } else if (b4.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer())) {
                                    b4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                }


                                Handler handler = new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DB7093"));
                                        b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DB7093"));
                                        b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DB7093"));
                                        b4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DB7093"));
                                        updateQuestion();
                                    }

                                }, 1500);

                            }
                        }

                    });

                    b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if ((b3.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer()))) {
                                b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                Handler handler = new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        correct++;
                                        b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DB7093"));

                                        updateQuestion();

                                    }
                                }, 1500);

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                wrong = wrong + 1;

                                b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                                if (b2.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer())) {
                                    b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                } else if (b1.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer())) {
                                    b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                } else if (b4.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer())) {
                                    b4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                }


                                Handler handler = new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DB7093"));
                                        b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DB7093"));
                                        b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DB7093"));
                                        b4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DB7093"));
                                        updateQuestion();
                                    }

                                }, 1500);

                            }
                        }

                    });

                    b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if ((b4.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer()))) {
                                b4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                Handler handler = new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        correct++;
                                        b4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DB7093"));

                                        updateQuestion();

                                    }
                                }, 1500);

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                wrong = wrong + 1;

                                b4.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                                if (b2.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer())) {
                                    b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                } else if (b3.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer())) {
                                    b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                } else if (b1.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer())) {
                                    b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                }


                                Handler handler = new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DB7093"));
                                        b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DB7093"));
                                        b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DB7093"));
                                        b4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DB7093"));
                                        updateQuestion();
                                    }

                                }, 1500);
                                updateQuestion();

                            }
                        }


                    });


                }

 }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

The XML activity looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".QuizActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/questiontxt"
        android:layout_width="352dp"
        android:layout_height="131dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="119dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="173dp"
        android:background="#DB7093"
        android:padding="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="146dp"
        android:layout_height="119dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:background="#DB7093"
        android:padding="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="119dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
        android:background="#DB7093"
        android:padding="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="119dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="84dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
        android:background="#DB7093"
        android:padding="8dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

And the JSON file in the database looks like this:

[image: JSON file in the database]

And the build.gradle(app) looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.scienceapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

 dependencies {
      implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      //noinspection GradleCompatible
      implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
      implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
      implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraintlayout:1.1.0-beta4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
   }apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

ALso i would like to mention that I have tried and set data in the firebase console using this activity using the method setText() and it works. The only issue seems to be retrieval of data.

I would really appreciate some help and any other resource to make the question more understandable. THANKS!!!

EDIT: This is the error that i am getting now on my phone when i run the application:

[image]

Comment: Post your `logcat` also

Comment: I have posted it.. Can you pls help?? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I am guessing that `1, 2` child nodes below `Questions` node are serially incremented.

1) When you initialized your database reference like this

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Questions").child(String.valueOf(total));
```

You are already in the `1` node (since initially *int total = 1;*). Hence,

```
for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
```

will not work. You will probably be getting an Exception. Hence I propose following changes:

```
private void updateQuestion() {

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Questions").child(String.valueOf(total));
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                DataSnapshot snapshot = dataSnapshot;
                /*final Question question = snapshot.getValue(Question.class);

                String ques = question.getQuestion();
                String op1 = question.getOption1();
                String op2 = question.getOption2();
                String op3 = question.getOption3();
                String op4 = question.getOption4();*/

                String ques = snapshot.child("question").getValue().toString();
                String op1 = snapshot.child("option1").getValue().toString();
                String op2 = snapshot.child("option2").getValue().toString();
                String op3 = snapshot.child("option3").getValue().toString();
                String op4 = snapshot.child("option4").getValue().toString();

                //### ADD THIS ALSO ###
                final String answer = snapshot.child("answer").getValue().toString();
                .......
```

2) Then replace every button check with this as well

```
//if ((b1.getText().toString().equals(question.getAnswer()))) {
if ((b1.getText().toString().equals(answer))) {
```

do this for b2, b3 and b4 as well.

3) Finally since your are on `1` node since value of total is 1. So increment total before calling `updateQuestion();`. Do everywhere, where you have called updateQuestion on button clicklisteners.

```
total++;    //<< Add this statement to jump to next node of firebase database
updateQuestion();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: since as per your question only retrival of firebase data was important but to complete the app functionality as a whole i added step 2nd and  3rd for a reference. Hope it helped but you can do it differently as you need. And welcome!